# Javascript embedded widget into a WordPress website is not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm embedding a widget into a WordPress website, using this script code in a custom HTML block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.cqc.org.uk/sites/all/modules/custom/cqc_widget/widget.js?data-id=1-13501952705&amp;data-host=https://www.cqc.org.uk&amp;type=provider"></script>
```

However, it only seems to display when I am logged into the site. When logged out, it doesn't display. When I check the console, I see the following error message.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at widget.js?ver=1668709233:1:606
    at widget.js?ver=1668709233:1:1755
```

Could this be related? Why might the widget only be displaying when logged into the website? How can I correct the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error log the file widget.js is having some issues which are due to some undefined data variables which are solved once the user logs in thats why this is happening.

I think so…

Comment: Sure, but I am wondering how to correct this for non-logged in users too. What do you think? Never really had this issue when embedding a javascript widget before.

Comment: You can do one thing go to the widget.js and check the lines mentioned in logged error and make the possible changes you can disable something if asking for user login or something